# Что делает данный скрипт php

Tags: php, php-curl

Скажите, пожалуйста, что делает данный код php

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

СПАСИБО!!!

Comment: глушит вывод ошибок и курлом вытаскивает контент страницы, который лежит по адресу, который закодирован в base64. И выполняет его.

Comment: где вы его нашли?

Comment: У меня на сайте появились откуда-то вот этот файл (называется civil.php),а в адмике wp плагин api-key и хост мне написал, что у меня вредоносный код

Comment: хост вас не обманул. Затащили скорее всего с очередным бесплатным плагином. Весь закаченный скрипт я вам сейчас не расскажу, но в общем там выполняется масса серверных скриптов и полный доступ ко всем данным всего вашего сайта и скорее всего через вас к остальным вашим сайтам и сайтам/ресурсам хоста, если хост дырявый. Не качайте бесплатные плагины.

Comment: обычно хосты запрещают выполнение функции eval на уровне конфигов, так что в этом конкретном случае может и прронесло.

Comment: Спасибо за ответы. Дело в том, что данный плагин никто не устанавливал. Могли ли мне занести это все через форму обратной связи? (contact form7 на WP). Есть ли способы проверит БД на заражение?

Comment: CF7 вроде без дыр в плане пользовательского ввода. Затащить вы его могли любым плагином. Маркет WP особо не заморачивается на этот счёт, это лишь вопрос вашей осторожности и добропорядосноти/не дырявости вендоров. Сам вендор иногда не знает, что его модуль несёт в себе каку.

Comment: Спасибо! Буду знать